# How to get the survival objects being created by the ctree?

Tags: r, classification

I would like to get the survival objects which are created by the ctree function. 
The reason is that I would like to get the vectors which describe the curves in each leaf of the tree.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance!
Alley

Comment: `ctree` is not a base R function. What package are you referring to? Some example code will also help you get your answer.

Comment: @Prasad, it is in package `party`. See `?ctree` after loading the package to get a simple survival tree example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the curves using the `treeresponse` method. There might be a much better way, but this is what I came up with.

Here is an illustration using the example of a survival tree from `?ctree`:

```
require(party)
data("GBSG2", package = "ipred")
GBSG2ct <- ctree(Surv(time, cens) ~ .,data = GBSG2)
plot(GBSG2ct)
```

We grab the (fitted) responses, using `treeresponse` for the training data. This is a list, with a component for each observation in the training data.

```
out <- treeresponse(GBSG2ct)
```

Each component out `out` is a survival object, class `"survfit"`

```
> class(out[[1]])
[1] "survfit"
```

For this tree we have four terminal nodes, so there are only four unique survival objects. You can use the `where` method to see which nodes the observations were in

```
wnode <- where(GBSG2ct)
```

We can use this index the unique survival objects. For example, for node 3 (the leftmost node in the plot of the tree)

```
> n3 <- which(wnode == 3 & !duplicated(wnode))
> n3
[1] 1
> out[[n3]]
> out[[n3]]
records   n.max n.start  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
    686     248     248      88    2093    1814      NA
```

The survival curve for node 3 can be plotted using the `plot` method:

```
plot(out[[n3]], conf.int = FALSE, mark.time = FALSE)
```

[image: suvival plot for node 3 of the example tree]

which, apart from the range on the axes is the plot used in the panel for node 3 on the tree drawn earlier.

For this example, you can repeat for nodes 4, 6 and 7, but you'll need to tailor which nodes you work with to your data and fitted tree.

Comment: Thank you very much Parsad! I will try it. Do you have any idea how can I use the argument 'surv' of a survival object? I would like to get the probability vectors which the curve is generated by. Thanks again - Alley

Comment: @Alley you need to look at the help for the survival package and also read `?survfit.object`

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I will look into it. You've been very helpful, sorry for not recognizing it was you last time.

Comment: Ok, using : out[[1]]$surv did work! :)
By the way, why did you write: out[[1]] and not out[1]? what does it mean? Thanks again

Comment: How about you go learn some R? `[` when applied to a list like this `out[1]` returns a list with a single component, the selected one. `[[` would return the object that is **in** that list.